# Do not replace NAs with 0 when extracting data from BEA API

Tags: r, api, get, r-markdown, na

When I use the code below to get BEA data, I do get the data on my R markdown. However, it converts all the NAs into zero and gives me a message that "NAs introduced by coercion." How can I make sure that NAs stay NAs, and do not turn into zeros.

```
beaPCI <- list(
    'UserID' = beaKey ,
    'Method' = 'GetData',
    'datasetname' = 'RegionalIncome',
    'TableName' = 'CA1' ,
    'LineCode' = '3',
    'Year' = '1992, 1996, 2000, 2004, 2008, 2012' ,
    'GeoFips' = 'COUNTY' ,
    'ResultFormat' = 'json'
);
beaPCI <- beaGet(beaPCI)
```

Comment: Where does `beaGet()` come from?

Comment: beaGet comes from the package bea.R which helps retrieve data from U.S. Bureau of Economic Analysis (BEA)'s API. I used this github page to get the codes: (https://github.com/us-bea/bea.R)

Answer (score 0):

The "NAs introduced by coercion" part occurs independent of the coercion of NA to 0. The two are not related. However, NA values in the data are indeed converted to 0. But this was done by design. In the package code, in the process of converting the data to data.table format, this happens:

```
#A weird fix to push NA values down to bottom for reshaping
beaTab[, DataValue := ifelse(is.na(DataValue), 0, DataValue)]
```

Seems like this was done as a workaround to some issue the author was having. So the NA values are changed to 0 and never changed back. I looked through the code and it looks like this is only done in the conversion to a data.table. So grabbing the data and exporting it as a list does not use the same method.

The code to produce the results in a list is:

```
beaGet(beaPCI, asTable = F, asList = T)
```

You need to include both options. If you do this, the NA values remain NA. The data still need to be reshaped if you use this method though.

Personally, I would just convert the zeros back to NA and save some time. We know that none of the data can actually be zero in this case.